# Java: Which is faster, arrays or objects?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

This question is purely regarding speed and efficiency, not minding which is the structural better approach.

Basically I need a view module to read a state, which is essentially an array of characters. These characters have a position, name, items etc.

Either I could make an array of character object with getters for the information, or I could represent each character as an array containing the same information.

Which of these two approaches would be faster for the view module to read?

example:
approach 1

```
for(int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++){
  Character temp = character[i];
  this.drawName(temp.getName());
  this.drawCharacterAt(temp.getColor(), temp.getX(), temp.getY())
  ....
}
```

approach 2

```
for(int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++){
  this.drawName(character[i][0]);
  this.drawCharacterAt(character[i][1],character[i][2],character[i][3]);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Seems like premature optimisation. There's no indication that one is going to be *noticeably* slower than the other, or that either approach is going to be slow enough to require any optimising, so go with the one that's the easiest to code, read and maintain. Or, in other words, use objects because they have specific properties and that makes a hell of a lot more sense.

Comment: What about testing it?

Comment: Only a benchmark test can answer that question definitely, but I would bet on the objects being faster; for the simple reason that the version with the array needs a lot of casting which means typechecking overhead in the JVM.

Comment: What an idea! You call something as slow as draw* and think about optimizing a single memory access.

Comment: @maaartinus Thank you for the input Mr. Condescending. I'll remember that the single slowest call in my programs should set the bar for optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference, at least after the JIT kicked in. Let's look at what happens in each case:

Case 1 array:

- we retrieve the array object's memory address from the character array
- we access the memory location of the first array element

Case 2 object:

- we retrieve the object's memory address from the character array
- we call the getter
- in the getter, we access the memory location of the name field

However the JIT will inline that getter call, making it:

- we retrieve the object's memory address from the character array
- we access the memory location of the name field

So, after the JIT is done with us, we pretty much end up with the same code. If the code is not executed often enough to be interesting for the JIT, then we can probably neglect the overhead anyway. Plus, with the getter it is easier to see what happens.

Comment: You forgot the array bounds check, which can't be always eliminated.

Comment: As mentioned above in the comments, I think the array version requires `checkcast` for every access that downcasts the `Object` in the array e.g. to `Integer`; I don't think the JIT can eliminate those checks.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 is more memory-efficient - it involves reading less data - which could make it faster. But the memory access pattern in approach 1 might be more friendly to caching/prefetching, which could be a larger effect. As with most performance questions, the only real answer is to profile your specific use case directly and see which is faster in practice.